# CSS + Show Animated GIF while <img> Loads

Tags: html, css

I want to show an Animated GIF while images loads and I want to do this using CSS. (eg: without JS if possible).

```
 <img src="images/users/girl1.png" class="thumbnailPreLoader memberImage"/>


 .thumbnailPreLoader {
     background: url('/images/image-preloader.gif') no-repeat scroll center center #F9F9F9;
     height: 101px;
     width: 101px;
     position: relative;
 }


 div#preferredMembers img.memberImage {
     border: 1px solid #808080;
     padding: 3px;
 }
```

Above is what I'm currently working with and you can see this at www.datingjapan.co (set of 5 thumbnail images).

I'm currently finding I just don't see the GIF.

If I go into chrome developer mode and change the path of the img I can see the GIF then so I know the path etc are correct.

Is this possible? Is there a trick I'm missing? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I know how to do this with jquery .load() but it would suit me much better to just attach a CSS class.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the `scroll` in `background: url('/images/image-preloader.gif') no-repeat scroll center center #F9F9F9;` It is not required here. It solved the issue in my chrome inspector...